# Current time using avplayer returns wrong values and same values ios

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I want to get current time of video playing using avplayer. I have used following code:-

```
let currentItem:AVPlayerItem = player!.currentItem
var currentTime:NSTimeInterval = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.currentTime())
println(currentTime)
```

This returns sometimes correct value i.e. proper time duration and sometimes stops at some value and does not give proper value. What can be reason behind this? Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We experience the same problem, it seems like some sort of race between the initialisation of the playerItem and getting the current time. If we do some sort of heavy activity (print the stack to the NSLog before accessing the currentTime) it will work

Comment: Hi. Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: @KarenAnne Yes above method is correct given in question itself. It stops at some value because  it goes in buffering state at that time and continue once come back from buffering.

Comment: Is it alright to get the current time for livestream channels?

Comment: @KarenAnne Yes it is working. I have used for live streaming

Comment: For our livestreaming, it always return 10 seconds initially for the currentTime. Should be 0, right? I wonder why..

Comment: @KarenAnne Yes it should be 0 Make sure you are creating AVPlayerItem here and not storing old value.